# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'video')

Tags: reactjs, computer-vision

I'm trying to make a emotion detection web app using ***React*** and ***face-api.js***

I have a switch that turns on the webcam, loads in the face-api.js models and starts detecting the face and emotions. My problem is whenever I 'turn off' the switch or leave the Camera.jsx component, I get spammed in the console:

[image]

This is the code to the Camera.jsx component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import * as face from 'face-api.js';
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import './Camera.css';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

const Camera = () => {
    const camHeight = 720;
    const camWidth = 1280;
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const displaySize = {
        width: camWidth,
        height: camHeight
    }

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
      };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (checked) {
            const MODEL_URL = `/models`
            const initModels = async () => {
                Promise.all([
                    face.loadTinyFaceDetectorModel(MODEL_URL),
                    face.loadFaceLandmarkModel(MODEL_URL),
                    face.loadFaceRecognitionModel(MODEL_URL),
                    face.loadFaceExpressionModel(MODEL_URL)
                ]);
            }
            initModels();
        }
    }, [checked]);

    const faceAnalysis = () => {
        face.matchDimensions(canvasRef.current, displaySize);
        setInterval(async () => {
            const detections = await face.detectAllFaces(videoRef.current.video, new face.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();
            const resizedDetections = face.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
            canvasRef.current.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, camWidth, camHeight);
            face.draw.drawDetections(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
            face.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
            face.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
        }, 50);
    }

    return (
        <div className="analysis">
            <Switch
                checked={checked}
                onChange={handleChange}
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
            />
            { checked ?  
            <div className="camera">
                <Webcam 
                    ref={videoRef} 
                    videoConstraints={displaySize}
                    onUserMedia={faceAnalysis} 
                />
                <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
            </div>
            : null}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Camera;
```

Would this be a problem with the way I'm loading in the models for the emotion detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by creating a function in the Camera.jsx component and surrounding it all with a try/catch block and clearing the interval in the catch like so:

```
    const drawFaceInterval = () => {
        setInterval(async () => {
            try {
                const detections = await face.detectAllFaces(videoRef.current.video, new face.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();
                const resizedDetections = face.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
                canvasRef.current.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, camWidth, camHeight);
                face.draw.drawDetections(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
                face.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
                face.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
            } catch (error) {
                clearInterval(drawFaceInterval);
            }
        }, 50);
    }
```

And calling it back in my faceAnalysis() function:

```
    const faceAnalysis = () => {
        face.matchDimensions(canvasRef.current, displaySize);
        drawFaceInterval();
    }
```